# remove selected option from drop-down available options

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a drop-down and I need to remove the selected option and show the remaining options. thanks in advance

```js
  FacultyorStudent_Data: Array<string> = ['Faculty/Coach','Student']
  selected_FacultyorStudent: string = this.FacultyorStudent_Data[0];
  
  SelectFacultyorStudent(FnS){
    this.selected_FacultyorStudent=FnS;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="text-center" id="perf-type" *ngIf="section=='practice'">
    <h4 class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">  <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      &nbsp; <b>{{selected_FacultyorStudent}} &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-down" 
        style="font-size: 0.7em; font-weight: 700;"></i></b>&nbsp;&middot;<small>beta v4</small>
    </h4>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 20%; left: 40%;color:  #337ab7;">
      <li *ngFor="let item of FacultyorStudent_Data; let i = index;" class="text-center"
        [ngClass]="{'bg-selected-quiz': selected_FacultyorStudent==item}"
        (click)="SelectFacultyorStudent(item)">
        {{item}}</li>

    </ul> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FacultyorStudent_Data array iterate it through loop , and match if item is equals to the item you want to remove.
If they match then remove it using splice method.

In you .ts file:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.FacultyorStudent_Data.length;i++){
   if(FacultyorStudent_Data[i]=='yourItemName'){
     this.FacultyorStudent_Data.splice(i,1)
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it showing any error, or just completely blank the array?

Comment: just blank I think there are no items in array

Answer (score 0):

```js
  if (FnS == 'Student'){
    this.FacultyorStudent_Data.splice(0,1,'Faculty | Coach Insights')
  }
  else{
    this.FacultyorStudent_Data.splice(0,1,'Student')
   }
   
  }
```